# Dump file is getting created and filling the space in drive

Tags: heap-memory, coredump

While running a standalone java application using .bat file , sometimes if the input file has large number of records , dump files getting created and thus filling up the space in the drive.

I am trying to increase heap memory in eclipse ,but while converting the application into a runnable jar file ,it is not taking the vm argument such as -Xmax 2048,-Xmas1024 etc. so the heap memory is not able to increase while running the jar file from a .bat file

java -Xmx2048m -Xms2048m
-version
set "curpath=%cd%"
start jdk file path\jdk\jdk\bin\javaw.exe -jar "Jarfile path /filename.jar" 
java -version
pause

Above is the line i wrote in the .bat file to run the jar file

According to me it should increase the heap memory and the the application should not hang and dump file should not be created .But I am still getting those dump file and these are filling up my drive space.

If anyone knows how to resolve this please help me.

Comment: specify -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError and this would not create any more dumps.

Comment: -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError in .bat file?